# Adding custom id field in flask/mongoengine document

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am working on revamping an application from Django/MySQL to flask/mongo-engine & am having trouble creating a model with an `id` field. This is a sample model:

```
class Location(db.Document):
    id = db.IntField(unique=True)
    name = db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    # other fields in the document ...
```

For backward compatibility, I require the field `id` named as is. This used to work fine in MySQL but mongo-engine gives the ValidationError -- `Field is required: ['id'] Invalid Object ID: ['auto_id_0']` for documents of the above model.

I also tried using the `db_field` parameter as in

```
id = db.IntField(db_field='l_id', unique=True)
```

...but to no avail.

**Do note that I have no intentions of overriding the default `ObjectID` field of mongodb.** Is there any workaround for this, other than renaming the field upon deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Location(db.Document):
    myid = db.IntField(db_field='id', unique=True)
    name = db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    # other fields in the document ...
```

And operate with it as if the field is named myid.

```
Location.objects.create(myid=real_id)
Location.objects.filter(myid=real_id)
```

Comment: This would override the default id field which stores the ObjectID. Anyways, I tried a lot and asked around a lot but found no method that would retain the original id field as well as add an application level model field named 'id' with some other db field name.
So I ended up adding a new field named l_id in the model & serializing it in my API responses.

Comment: Yea. I finally realized that document copies _id into id field in mongoengine however I specified custom name for db_field

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
class Location(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField()
    id = db.IntField(unique=True)
    name = db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    # other fields in the document ...
```

This caused the `id` IntField() to correctly grab the `id` field from Mongo.